# node.js writing to client after getting posting to server

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, request, response

so i send a `POST` from the client to the my node server, then get that data

```
 var http = require('http');
 http.createServer(function(req, res){
   var data = "";
   req.on('data', function(chunk){
      data += chunk;
   });
   req.on('end', function(){
      var doSomething = function doSomethingWithData(data){.....};
      //here is where i want to send data back to the client
      // i tried doing a res.write(); didnt work
   });
 }).listen(8080);

console.log("Server started");`
```

I tried looking this up but i found nothing, I figured I wasn't asking the right question,
the client side is using jquery `post` and `get` functions

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on "didnt work?" Did you also `res.end()` the response after you were finished writing?

Comment: yes i did try that, and what i mean by didnt is undefined:0

^
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)

Comment: Ok, so you're doing `JSON.parse()` and it's throwing because the input json is not valid. In that case you should wrap `JSON.parse()` in a `try { } catch() {}` and do something like `res.writeHead(400); res.end();` if you catch an error like that.

Comment: //all require node modules
var http = require('http');
    
//create http server
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    console.log("Getting request from client");
    var data = "";
    
    //getting data
    req.on('data', function(chunk){
        data += chunk;
    });
    req.on('end', function(){
        var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(parsed.id);
        //checking id of reqest  
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/plain", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" })
        res.end("SOMEthing");
    });
}).listen(8080);
console.log("Server Started");